# excel countif multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a summary sheet with names in one column and I want to consolidate (count) the names which are appearing in different sheets on the same workbook.  Names are not necessarily appear in same Columns across all worksheets.  Column is changed in every sheet.  I am using excel 2010 version.

```
Summary Sheet
NameA
NameB
NameC

Sheet2
In column L, I have these names (NameA, NameB, Namec, etc.)
Sheet3
In Column M, I have these names (NameA, NameB, Namec, etc.)
Sheet4
In column K, I have these names (NameA, NameB, Namec, etc.)
```

Comment: Your question appears to incomplete. Please [edit] it to include what version you are using, what you have tried, and what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Formula:
`=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$L:$L,A2)+COUNTIF(Sheet3!$M:$M,A2)+COUNTIF(Sheet4!$K:$K,A2)`

A2 is the first name in the summary sheet (NameA in your example)
in B2 write the formula
$L:$L the names in sheet2 in column L
$M:$M the names in sheet3 in column M
$K:$K the names in sheet4 in column K
even when you add more names in the corresponding columns it will be counted